# Exporting an Acceleo 3.0 generator as an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, eclipse-pdt, acceleo

I have created a code generator based on Acceleo 3.0. I am trying now to deploy it as an Eclipse plugin in order to be able to install it on different instances, but I didn't succed.

I created a Feature project, then I added the generator projet to it then I exported as a deployable feature. After that, and with a new instance of Eclipse, I installed it using the Software Install Tool. It is installed but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Have a nice day.

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is not a helpful description of what is going wrong. What is not working?

Comment: sorry, I will try to be more clear. Well, the exported feature project was installed. It contains the generator projet and the ui project (which adds a popmenu when you click right on the model to be transformed into code). When I click right on the model I want to transform , and I choose Acceleo Generate Code, The directory "src-gen" is being created, but the actual file that contains the generated code is not created.

Comment: Another detail :) . In the UI project there's : IContainer target = model.getProject().getFolder("src-gen");
        GenerateAll generator = new GenerateAll(modelURI, target, getArguments());
        generator.doGenerate(monitor);  The directory src-gen is being created, this is  why I believe the problem comes from the instruction right after it, which instanciate the generator.